# Problems with Odoo 13 Domain filtering

Tags: odoo-13

i want to make a price selection for odoo.

I set it as one2many on product.product. It only consists of a field price type and a price.

What i want is the following:

```
choosable price_types should be apple, peach or lemon

- no price selection records created:
-- domain for type_id is apple, peach or lemon
- 1 record created with type apple:
-- domain for record 1: type_id is apple, peach or lemon
-- domain for new record: type_id is peach or lemon
- second record created with typle peach:
-- domain for record 1: type_id is apple or lemon
-- domain for record 2: type_id is peach or lemon
-- domain for new record: type_id is lemon
- third record created with typle lemon:
-- domain for record 1: type_id is apple
-- domain for record 2: type_id is peach
-- domain for record 3: type_id is lemon
-- new record: no further record could be created as no type_id left
```

the reason i want to keep the actual selected value per record in the domain is that odoo doesn't seem to like if i remove the currently selected value from the domain

My price selection is below class "product_draft_prices". price_type is the field type_id and the combination (type_id, product_id) has to be unique.

is the above mentioned filtering possible with domain filter ? The price types are stored in the separate table product_draft_pr_types especially for domain filtering.

So i want to set a domain filter on record basis.

I think the closest existing widget for this to refer is the many2manywidget. Here you can also choose only records which are not already assigned.

product Expansion

```
class product_product(models.Model):
_inherit = 'product.product'

product_draft_prices = fields.One2many('product.product.draft_prices', 'product_id', string='Produktpreise', copy=True, auto_join=True)
```

Product price table

```
class product_draft_prices(models.Model):
_name = 'product.product.draft_prices'
_description = 'product.product.draft_prices'

_sql_constraints = [('unique_type', 'unique(type_id, product_id)',
                     'Fehler bei Produktpreisen:\n\nDieser Preistyp ist ' + \
                     'für dieses Produkt schon vergeben, bitte anderen auswählen')]

product_id  = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Produkt', required=True, copy=False)
type_id     = fields.Many2one('product.product.draft_pr_types', required=True, string="Preistyp")
name        = fields.Char('Name des Produktpreises')
price       = fields.Float('Preiseingabe', required=True, digits='Product Price')
```

Product price types

```
class product_draft_pr_types(models.Model):
_name = 'product.product.draft_pr_types'
_description = 'product.product.draft_pr_types'

types = ['apple', 'peach', 'melon']

name = fields.Char('Preistyp')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You question is not cleared.I don't know exactly what you want. Please describe clearly what exactly you want.

Comment: rephrased my question, hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.I don't know exactly it will work or not.
I wish even it cannot be solved, you may get some reference.

```html
class product_draft_prices(models.Model):
_name = 'product.product.draft_prices'
_description = 'product.product.draft_prices'

_sql_constraints = [('unique_type', 'unique(type_id, product_id)',
                     'Fehler bei Produktpreisen:\n\nDieser Preistyp ist ' + \
                     'für dieses Produkt schon vergeben, bitte anderen auswählen')]

product_id  = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Produkt', required=True, copy=False)
type_id     = fields.Many2one('product.product.draft_pr_types', required=True, string="Preistyp")
name        = fields.Char('Name des Produktpreises')
price       = fields.Float('Preiseingabe', required=True, digits='Product Price')

@api.onchange('type_id','product_id.product_draft_prices')
def onchange_type_id(self):
    price_list=[]
    for plist in self.product_id.product_draft_prices:
      price_list.append(plist.type_id.price_type.id)
    return {'domain':{'type_id':[('price_type','not in',price_list)]}}
```

Change your selection field into many2one.

```html
class product_draft_pr_types(models.Model):
_name = 'product.product.draft_pr_types'
_description = 'product.product.draft_pr_types'

types = field.many2one(product.type,string="Type")
name = fields.Char('Preistyp')

class type(models.Model):
_name = "product.type"

name= field.Char(string="Type name")
```

Comment: thanks for the heads up, i got it working now.

i expanded your method _onchange_type_id to still allow the same value as the line has. This gives me correct values while editing. And i added another many2many field type_ids with api.depends to store the correct value while saving, so i can reopen the records and the values are still correct

Comment: @MiCha. If my answer help you, can you press my answer is useful button?

Answer (score 0):

so my code looks like this now

```
class product_draft_prices(models.Model):
_name = 'product.product.draft_prices'
_description = 'product.product.draft_prices'

_sql_constraints = [('unique_type', 'unique(type_id, product_id)',
                     'Fehler bei Produktpreisen:\n\nDieser Preistyp ist ' + \
                     'für dieses Produkt schon vergeben, bitte anderen auswählen')]

@api.depends('type_ids','product_id.product_draft_prices')
def _get_type_ids(self):
    for record in self:
        price_list = []
        for plist in record.product_id.product_draft_prices:
            if record.type_id and record.type_id.name and record.type_id.name == plist.type_id.name:
                continue
            price_list.append(plist.type_id.id)
        record.type_ids = [(6, 0, price_list)]

product_id  = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Produkt', required=True, copy=False)
type_id     = fields.Many2one('product.product.draft_pr_types', required=True, string="Preistyp")
type_ids    = fields.Many2many('product.product.draft_pr_types', required=True, string="Preistypen zur Auswahl", store=True, compute=_get_type_ids)
name        = fields.Char('Name des Produktpreises')
price       = fields.Float('Preiseingabe', required=True, digits='Product Price')

@api.onchange('type_id','product_id.product_draft_prices')
def _onchange_type_id(self):
    price_list = []
    for plist in self.product_id.product_draft_prices:
        if self.type_id and self.type_id.name and self.type_id.name == plist.type_id.name:
            continue
        price_list.append(plist.type_id.name)
    return {'domain': {'type_id': [('name', 'not in', price_list)]}}
```

and these 2 lines for the view

```
<field name="type_ids" invisible="1"/>
<field name="type_id" domain="[('id', 'not in', type_ids)]"/>
```

the domain for field type_id gets overriden at runtime with the currently selected value, so problem solved

Answer (score 0):

```
The filter_domain attribute can contain an arbitrary domain, so you're restricted neither to searching for the same field you named in the name attribute nor to using only one term.
      
 <record id="account_tax_view_search" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="name">account.tax.search.filters</field>
                <field name="model">account.tax</field>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <search string="Search Taxes">
                        <field name="name" filter_domain="['|', ('name','ilike',self), ('description','ilike',self)]" string="Tax"/>
                        <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company"/>
                    </search>
                </field>
            </record>
```